# Can't find file for Ubuntu 64 bit to load into the pendrivelionux program

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 64 bit through a bootable usb. I downloaded the software but I can't find the file to add to the pendrivelinux program. What is the file called and where is it located?

Answer (score 2):

You have first to [download the ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)  Once that is done, make sure you save it to a known location.  Proceed with either [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

> The recommended way to install Ubuntu from a USB flash drive is to use
>   the usb-creator program, point it at a ISO image of a Ubuntu
>   installation CD that you have downloaded, and let it create a bootable
>   USB that you can use instead of the CD.

<sup>Source: [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)</sup>